# makefile for serial communication between two processors (gcc)

Tags: gcc, makefile, uart, msp430, contiki

i have to program two processors (STM 32 and MSP 430). the algorithm is:

Process 1: do algorithm 1

Process 1: Send hello to process 2

Process 2 : reply msg to process 1

Process 2: do its  algorithm 2 when finished send a msg to process 1 (data exchange)

Process 1: read data and do algorithm 1

The processors are linked via wires (UART). the compiler is gcc. i have the same OS (contiki).

I have the differents APIs, files of device and protocols of communication for each layer.

My question is how to program those processors to communicate via UART? write a one .c file? or two ?

Can i write a makefile or i have to write two makefiles?

Please i need help. I looked for solution but i didn't got any clear solution. I greatly appreciate your help.

Best regards.

Comment: You need to edit the tags with appropriate ones.  Why "unix"?  Your question make no mention of Unix.  "SoC" is not appropriate. Usually neither the STM32 or MSP430 are considered "SoC" since they do not have a MMU, but rather are classified as microcontrollers,.

Comment: It is Okay. i modified the  tags :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn proper terminology, the meaning of technical terms and the realization that you have two different hardware systems.

> The processors are linked via wires (UART).

Connecting two UARTs to each other establishes a *serial communications link*.

> the compiler is gcc.

The STM32 and MSP430 are of different CPU architectures, so they cannot use the same (cross)compiler.  You can use the GNU GCC toolchain, but you need one built just for the STM32, and another built just for the MSP430.

> i have the same OS.

Which is what?
Something like FreeRTOS or NuttX RTOS or uClinux?

> Can i write a makefile or i have to write two makefiles?

You have two different hardware systems, so you need two toolchains.
You need two makefiles.

> My question is how to program those processors to communicate via UART? write a one .c file? or two ?

You have two different hardware systems, so you need two programs.
If you have chosen the OS for each microcontroller wisely, then there will be a basic port (version) and some device drivers for the microcontroller installed on a reference board.  If you are using some other board, then you will probably have to make modification (e.g. pin changes and/or port assignments).

> the algorithm is:
>
> Process 1: do algorithm 1
>
> Process 1: Send hello to process 2
>
> Process 2 : reply msg to process 1
>
> Process 2: do its algorithm 2 when finished send a msg to process 1 (data exchange)
>
> Process 1: read data and do algorithm 1

You have not clearly described what you expect to accomplish.
We can guess that "Process 1" and "algorithm 1" are executing on one microcontroller, and that "Process 2" and "algorithm 2" are executing on the other microcontroller.
Perhaps "Process x" is actually supposed to mean "processor x" or "microcontroller x"?

You need to be cognizant that each microcontroller is executing completely independent from the other microcontroller.  Proper operation of the message exchanging requires synchronization, which means that there has to be recovery methods if a message repeats or arrives out of order.  You cannot expect a perfect world where both microcontrollers are started simultaneously and naturally maintain message synchronization.  A well-designed and robust system should allow for either microcontroller to be restarted at any time, and then regain message synchronization.

> I looked for solution but i didn't got any clear solution.

You need to break up this project into smaller pieces.

A.
Install a toolchain for the STM32.
Get the RTOS running on the STM32.
Verify serial port operation with a simple loopback program using a **terminal emulator program** on a PC.

B.
Install a toolchain for the MSP430.
Get the RTOS running on the MSP430.
Verify serial port operation with a simple loopback program using a **terminal emulator program** on a PC.

C.
Design a message exchange protocol.
Your initial proposal seems to be a peer-to-peer scheme.  That can make the design difficult to be robust.
A master-slave relationship between the two microcontrollers leads to a simpler and more robust system.  The master is always in charge.  The slave never sends anything unless the master requests it.  The master will periodically query the slave with a poll message.  That is the slave's opportunity to respond with its status or calculation results.

D.
Learn about [**state machines**](http://blog.markshead.com/869/state-machines-computer-science/).
Learn how to write a program to implement a state machine.
Transform the message exchange protocol to a state machine.
Transform the steps or phases that each microcontroller needs to perform for the message exchange into a state machine for each side.

E.
Implement each side.  Test. Integrate.  Test.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and advises.

The OS used is contiki. It has two compilers of STM32 and MSP430 installed. i have some device drivers installed in contiki but i have to install the others one (i hope that i won't face problems in this part).

About my words that i used, process1 is microprocessor 1 will execute palgorithm 1 (program and functions).

Now i'm learning about synchronisation between microcontrollers and about state machines to have my robust system and to have a good strategy.